# Is it recommended to have a static variable that maintains state?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, object, static-methods

I have an encryption utility method that relies on an external dependency --- a cipher key which is being retrieved from a property file. The way it can be retrieved in the current code base which I inherited is that it relies on creating new objects to be able to get the value of a property in the properties file. For example, if wanted to get the Cipher Key from the property file, it would be like this:

```
    public synchronized static String encrypt(String someTextToEncrypt) {
             String propertyValue = null;
             propertyValue = getProcessCommonBase().
                                getProcessProperties.getProperty("CIPHER_KEY");
                     /*encrypt algorithm*/
             return encryptedForm;
        } 
    private synchronized static ProcessCommonBase getProcessCommonBase() {
            if (processCommonBase == null) {
                 processCommonBase = new ProcessCommonBase();
            }
            return processCommonBase;
    }
    private static ProcessCommonBase processCommonBase;
```

**EDITED:** Design-wise is having a something like the processCommonBase instance variable a good practice to do? My understanding is that a good practice is that static variables should be final and do not change. In this case, however, the ProcessCommonBase class maintains state and is subject to change.

**NEW QUESTION:** If the static method relies on something external shouldn't I just mark the method and the processCommon base variable as non static and in Spring, just make a bean definition for it? What is better?

Comment: Static method calls should be avoided. You should use a singleton object for that, a Spring bean is such a singleton.

Answer (score 1):

Someone already commented your specific case, but in general, what you described is an *effectively final* static variable, which is just created "lazily" (that is, only when needed). It's a fine approach, if creating a `ProcessCommonBase` instance is an expensive and rare event, although you must be careful to access it only via the getter method then. On the other hand, if a `ProcessCommonBase` will be created whenever the surrounding class is used, then making it actually final is a better approach: it's simpler (less error prone, as you don't need to remember to use the getter method exclusively), and will actually be a bit cheaper, as the final variable is initialized only when the surrounding class is first used, and you don't need the (synchronized!) null check every time when accessing it (of course, if you use > 1 threads and`ProcessCommonBase` isn't thread-safe, then you need to synchronize somewhere).

Answer to your second question: being static vs. not and relying on some external system properties are two separate things. I don't know what Spring does, but if your method essentially a function - "value in, result out" - then it's a static method by its nature, even if it reads its configuration from some system property. Making such methods instance methods is possible, but if it only complicates things and gives nothing, why bother?

Comment: Wouldn't it be unsafe if ProcessCommonBase had setter methods and then you could change its state? It might affect the outputs of other static methods that rely on it.

Comment: Of course it's unsafe if `ProcessCommonBase` itself is mutable (for example, if it has setters that someone could use). But in that case it would be unsafe regardless of if it's made `final`, or created lazily. `final` only applies to the reference, it has no powers to keep the object being referenced immutable. But even if `ProcessCommonBase` has setters, you can make it "effectively immutable" if you simply don't use those setters (and don't allow anyone else to use them either; make it private).

Comment: Thanks for your follow up answer. I thoroughly understood that. But I 've added a new question. Cheers. :)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Joonas. I don't see why not make the variable final. Could you elaborate please what exactly do you mean by this:

> My understanding is that a good practice is that static variables should be final and do not change. In this case, however, the ProcessCommonBase class maintains state and is subject to change.

Even if the variable is final, you still can change the object it references to in exactly the same ways as you'd do it with a non-final variable. That's why it's perfectly fine for a static method to have a static variable maintaining its state, but nothing stops you from actually making it final in this case. Why not do this:

`private static ProcessCommonBase processCommonBase = new ProcessCommonBase();`

Maybe there's something stopping you from creating processCommonBase at static initialization time, but it isn't obvious from the information you have provided.

Comment: Nope nothing is stopping me from marking processCommonBase as final. Edited my question btw.

Comment: Then you better do it. `final` doesn't mean `const`, that's why it is even named differently. `final` just means that it will point to the same object all the time, but that's exactly what you want in this case. So design-wise it is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

The usage of static is often frowned upon from an OO design perspective because it gives tight coupling between objects. With statics methods it’s impossible to decouple an interface from its actual implementation. This lack of decoupling can for example become a problem when you want to unit test a single class, as it can’t be separated from the other static parts.

In today’s Java landscape you’re singleton crypt class can be much better designed with the help of [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) (DI). The ProcessCommonBase could also be implemented as an DI singleton if it didn’t had that very strong code smell, because if it’s a [god-object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object) then it should be refactored, for example by using DI for injecting properties into you crypt class.

Example code based on Google Guice:

```
@Singleton
public MyCrypt {
  private final key;

  @Inject
  MyCrypt(@CipherKey String key) {
    this.pBase = pBase;
  }

  public synchronized String encrypt(String someTextToEncrypt) { 
    /*encrypt algorithm*/ 
    return encryptedForm; 
  }  
}
```

Configuring DI properties:

```
public class PropertiesModule extends AbstractModule {

  @Override
  protected void configure() {
    String key = .. what ever ..
    bind(String.class).annotatedWith(CiperKey.class).toInstance(key);
  }
```

More DI examples can be found here:
http://java.dzone.com/articles/cdi-overview-part-1

Populair Java DI implementations are: [Guice](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/), [Spring](http://www.springsource.org/) and [Java EE6](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/overview/index.html).

Comment: It was mentioned below that it wasn't safe to put the cipher key in a properties file let alone a spring configuration file. :)

Comment: With DI you don't have to put it into a property file nor into any configuration file. It's all up to you.